# Reading lines from file and adding to another SHELL

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to solve the following problem:
I have two files, one congaing lines I wish to read one by one, and other file in which I want to add these lines, after the first occurrence of the pattern. For example, one file contains:

```
cat
dog
mouse
```

and other file contais

```
> <Name>
       blabla1


$$$$
> <Name>
       blabla2


$$$$
> <Name>
        blabla3


$$$$
```

I'd like to get it like this:

```
> <Name>
       blabla1
><My_addition>
cat
$$$$
> <Name>
       blabla2
><My_addition>
dog
$$$$
> <Name>
        blabla3
><My_addition>
mouse
$$$$
```

What I'm doing at the moment is:

```
filename="test.txt"
while read -r line
do
    a="$line"
    sed -i '0,/$$$$/s//<My_addition>\n'"$fingerprint"'\n\n$$$$/'  my_test.sdf >test_02.sdf
done < "$filename"
```

but that only changes the last occurrence (mouse). I also managed to add 'mouse' to all of them, but can't figure out how to add each line after one pattern occurrence.

To make it clearer, I am trying to insert first line from file 2 before first pattern occurrence in file 1, second line from file 2 before second patter occurrence in file 1, etc. So far, I am getting either last line before any pattern occurrence, or last line before last occurrence

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Input file are XML or HTML isn't it ?

Comment: @Gilles , input files are txt and sdf (structure-data file) files

Comment: So you should use a proper SDF parser (not a regex based tool like sed)

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to be able to avoid it. Can it be done using regex tools? Also, I am not sure 'sql-server' and 'sdf' tags are correct here...This is different sdf file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#SDF

Comment: Removed wrong tags, but there's a perl SDK there : https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/SDF_toolkit/ AND https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Chemistry-Mok/mok

Comment: I fully agree with Gilles -- using syntax-aware tools is the Right Thing. That said, are you saying you want to insert a line from file 1 before each line containing only `$$$$` from file 2? If so, the question should perhaps specify this more clearly -- not just by example, but with an explicit English-prose description of the desired logic.

Comment: @Charles, thank you, I will try and work with the parsers. I was hoping to be able to do it using shell script, as this is only a step in a process, and it would be much easier if it could be done without having to install extra tools. I am trying to insert first line from file 2 before first pattern occurrence in file 1, second line from file 2 before second patter occurrence in file 1, etc. So far, I am getting either last line before any pattern occurrence, or last  line before last occurrence.

Comment: Have you attempted the approach given in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: For your specific use case at hand, you should use a real parser.

Second: If you want to merge two files, open each on a separate file descriptor, and `read` from each as appropriate; see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a description of the `while read` construct. There's no need to use `sed` for this job.

```
#!/bin/sh

in1=$1
in2=$2

while IFS= read -r line1 <&3; do : line1="$line1" # debugging
  case $line1 in
    '$$$$')  # when we read a "$$$$" from file 1, write a line from file2 before it
        IFS= read -r line2 <&4 || {
          echo "ERROR: Ran out of lines in $in2 before finishing $in1" >&2
          printf '%s\n' "$line1"; cat <&3; break
        }
        printf '%s\n' '><My_addition>' "$line2" "$line1"
        ;;
    *)
        printf '%s\n' "$line1"
        ;;
  esac
done 3<"$in1" 4<"$in2"
```

---

When saved as `annotate-sdf` and run as follows:

```
cat >test.txt <<'EOF'
cat
dog
mouse
EOF

cat >test.sdf <<'EOF'
> <Name>
       blabla1
$$$$
> <Name>
       blabla2
$$$$
> <Name>
        blabla3
$$$$
EOF

./annotate-sdf test.sdf test.txt
```

...output is, as expected:

```
> <Name>
       blabla1
><My_addition>
cat
$$$$
> <Name>
       blabla2
><My_addition>
dog
$$$$
> <Name>
        blabla3
><My_addition>
mouse
$$$$
```

Comment: That's it! Does exactly what I need! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing [sdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#SDF) file with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) ot [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), you should use a real parser. Fortunately, there's one here : [Perl's Chemistry-Mok](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Chemistry-Mok/mok)